# vb6 random number no duplicates & no zeros

Tags: random, vb6

I am using vb6 and trying to generate a random number or String with this format
S1 = "378125649"

I have three requirements NO Duplicates Values & No Zeros & 9 charcters in length
I have approached This two very different ways the random number generator method is failing the FindAndReplace works but is too much code

**The questions are**

**How to fix the GetNumber method code to meet the three requirement?

OR

How to simplify the FindAndReplace code to reflect a completely new sequence of numbers each time?**

GetNumber code Below

```
Private Sub GetNumber()

Randomize
Dim MyRandomNumber As Long 'The chosen number
Dim RandomMax As Long 'top end of range to pick from
Dim RandomMin As Long 'low end of range to pick from
'Dim Kount As Long 'loop to pick ten random numbers

RandomMin = 1
RandomMax = 999999999

MyRandomNumber = Int(Rnd(1) * RandomMax) + RandomMin
lbOne.AddItem CStr(MyRandomNumber) & vbNewLine
End Sub
```

The FindAndReplace Code Below

```
Private Sub FindAndReplace()

    Dim S4 As String
    S4 = "183657429"
    Dim T1 As String
    Dim T2 As String
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim H As Integer
    
    J = InStr(1, S4, 2)
    H = InStr(1, S4, 8)
    T1 = Replace(S4, CStr(J), "X")
    T1 = Replace(T1, CStr(H), "F")


    If Mid(T1, 8, 1) = "F" And Mid(T1, 2, 1) = "X" Then
    T2 = Replace(T1, "F", "8")
    T2 = Replace(T2, "X", "2")
    End If

    tbOne.Text = CStr(J) & " " & CStr(H)
    lbOne.AddItem "Original Value " & S4 & vbNewLine
    lbOne.AddItem "New Value      " & T2 & vbNewLine
End Sub
```

Comment: @Brian M Stafford Thanks for the EDIT The last word in a lot of my code jumps out of the code when I do the paste I do not know if it is the VB 6 IDE or something I am doing wrong ?

Comment: If the code is indented 4 spaces when pasting it should be good.  However, I always select the code in the edit window and press the "code" button.

Comment: You really should be calling `Randomize` ONCE in your application, not every time your function gets called.  Do this in the Load() event of your form.

Comment: With those requirements, just start with the string "123456789" and shuffle the order of the characters.  For each index position in the string, pick another position and swap the values.  Done.  Guaranteed nine digits with no zeroes, "randomized".

Comment: @Idle Mind YES need to move it to Form Load YES that is what the Sub FindAndReplace does I was looking for a little less code Thinking of a For Next Loop to set the values Work in progress MORE work than PROGRESS

Comment: When you said no duplicate values, did you mean that all 9 digits are different or did you mean the final result should be unique because eventually, you will encounter the same generated random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a VB6 compiler, so I winged it:

```
Function GetNumber(lowerLimit as Integer, upperLimit As Integer) As Integer
    Dim randomNumber As String
    Dim numbers As New Collection
        
    Randomize

    For i As Integer = lowerLimit To upperLimit
        Call numbers.Add(i)
    Next

    For j As Integer = upperLimit To lowerLimit Step -1
        Dim position As Short = Int(((j - lowerLimit)* Rnd) + 1)

        randomNumber = randomNumber & numbers(position)
         
        Call numbers.Remove(position)
    Next
        
    Return(CInt(randomNumber))
End Function
```

Use that function by calling for example:

```
GetNumber(1, 9)
```

Comment: Nguyan Working on it FYI need to Dim first in VB6 like this Dim i As Integer

Comment: After removing all the syntax errors, this code works if the goal is to have every digit unique.

Comment: @Nya Nguyen Got the code to work need a little editing

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way of generating 9-digit random numbers with no zeroes.  The basic idea is to build a 9-character string position by position where each position is a random number between 1 and 9.  Then each string is added to a collection to remove any duplicates.  This code will generate 100,000 unique numbers:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim c As Collection
   Set c = GetNumbers()
   
   MsgBox c.Count
End Sub

Private Function GetNumbers() As Collection
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim i As Integer
   Dim n As String
   
   Randomize
   Set GetNumbers = New Collection
   
   Do While GetNumbers.Count < 100000
      n = ""
   
      For i = 1 To 9
         n = n & Int((9 * Rnd) + 1)
      Next
   
      GetNumbers.Add n, n
   Loop
End Function
```

In my testing, this code only generated 2 duplicates for the 100,000 unique numbers returned.

Comment: Great Code short and sweet It does as you said NO UNIQUENESS Add to Dictionary like a Text String ?

Comment: Does vb6 have a String Builder and I could reject the number if it was already in the StringBuilder HMM ?

Comment: I ran the code 10,000 times with no dups.  How many unique numbers do you need?

Comment: VB6 has no StringBuilder which is why I recommended either a collection or dictionary.

Comment: OK Now I know what a Collection is NOW how to Add and Remove https://www.fortypoundhead.com/showcontent.asp?artid=24286

Comment: I updated my example to show the use of collections.

Comment: The "On Error Resume Next" worries me because it is there.

Comment: @NyaNguyen On Error is there so the Add method doesn't fail with duplicate entries.  It's also the only line likely to generate an error.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford I might be implementing your code wrong What I did is call the Command_Click1 then it calls the GetNumbers Function the output is 100000 that takes about 3 seconds to execute Let me Play a little Will comment tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

I don't have VB6 on my machines anymore, so here's a solution written in Excel that shuffles the digits in 123456789 using an array.

You should be able to use it with little conversion:

```
Private Function RndNumber() As String
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim digits As Variant
    digits = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
    For i = 0 To UBound(digits)
        j = Int(9 * Rnd)
        tmp = digits(i)
        digits(i) = digits(j)
        digits(j) = tmp
    Next
    RndNumber = Join(digits, "")
End Function
```

Here's a variation to play with that will shuffle an array you pass in and join them together with the specified separator.  Note that the arrays being passed in are of variant type so anything can be shuffled.  The first array has numbers while the second array has strings:

```
Private Sub Foo()
    Dim digits As Variant
    digits = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    
    Dim rndNnumber As String
    RndNumber = ShuffleArrayAndJoin(digits, "")
    Debug.Print RndNumber
    
    Dim pets As Variant
    pets = Array("cat", "dog", "fish", "hamster")
    Dim rndPets As String
    rndPets = ShuffleArrayAndJoin(pets, ", ")
    Debug.Print (rndPets)
End Sub

Private Function ShuffleArrayAndJoin(ByVal sourceArray As Variant, ByVal separator As String) As String
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim tmp As Variant
    For i = 0 To UBound(sourceArray)
        j = Int(UBound(sourceArray) * Rnd)
        tmp = sourceArray(i)
        sourceArray(i) = sourceArray(j)
        sourceArray(j) = tmp
    Next
    ShuffleArrayAndJoin = Join(sourceArray, separator)
End Function
```

Comment: I did a copy and paste and it works great NOW to disect it and understand the code Are you converting digits to Strings ? I think not My VB.net machine is down so I am playing with my old VB6 development computer

Comment: The digits are being converted to strings.  In fact, you could change the type of "digits" and "tmp" to `Variant`, then populate the array with strings from the start. `Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")` It'd work exactly the same.  Additionally, we can get rid of the loop at the end that builds the result and simply use `RndNumber = Join(digits, "")`.

Comment: Odd Issue each time I click to generate a number the sequence is always the same Click 3 times Exit App Reload Click 3 times same sequence of numbers HMM any Ideas about a FIX ?  Digits new concept for me does this work in VB.Net ? My VB.Net Machine is in the shop

Comment: Make sure you have that `Randomize` call in a place that occurs only once, like the Load() event.  Don't have it in the function itself as if you click a button very quickly, for instance, or call it from within a loop, then the Timer function (which will be the seed) can return the same value and you'll get the same "random" numbers.

Comment: Are you putting a seed after Randomize by chance?

Comment: I forgot the Randomize dumb very dumb moved it to Form Load and forgot I deleted Form Load during  testing IT seems to be working now Thanks I even got Nya Nguyen Code to work

Comment: In VB6 with `Dim i, j As Integer` variable `i` is dimensioned of `Variant` data-type and `Integer` is 16-bit while `Long` is 32-bit wide and is generally faster to use on x86. `Dim i As Long, j As Long` should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @wqw, it's been a long time since I coded in classic VBA/VB6.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetNumber() As String
    Dim mNum As String
    Randomize Timer
    Do While Len(mNum) <> 9
        mNum = Replace(Str(Round(Rnd(Timer), 6)) + Str(Round(Rnd(Timer), 3)), " .", "")
    Loop
    GetNumber = mNum
End Function
```

Been clicking a button to load a text box for a couple of minutes, but so far no dupes, and I'd bet money there never will be any..

Comment: I got duplicate on 106th call -- https://pastebin.com/bqtnK50a

Answer (score 0):

Well, it solves just 1 problem: it will never ever repeat number
but it has to be 15+ numbers long...

```
Function genRndNr(nrPlaces)  'must be more then 10
    Dim prefix As String
    Dim suffix As String
    Dim pon As Integer
    prefix = Right("0000000000" + CStr(DateDiff("s", "2020-01-01", Now)), 10)
    suffix = Space(nrPlaces - 10)
    For pon = 1 To Len(suffix)
        Randomize
        Randomize Rnd * 1000000
        Mid(suffix, pon, 1) = CStr(Int(Rnd * 10))
    Next
    genRndNr = prefix + suffix
End Function
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some comments to your answer to explain how this solves the problem?